# Multi-Threaded program with two threads in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, operating-system, system

I have a multi-threaded program that we are examining in my Systems Engineering class. 
The program is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// repeat the times (*) operation 100,000 times to slow down the
// execution of the instructions
#define RPT 100000

void* print_X() {
   int i;
   float x;
   while (1) {
   // the multiplication operation below is for consuming some CPU       
   //time to slow down the execution

   for(i=0; i<RPT; i++) { 
   x = 3.1415926*3.1415926; 
}
   printf("X"); 
   }
 } 


void* print_O() {
   int i;float x;

   while (1) {
   // the multiplication operation below is for consuming some CPU       
   //time to slow down the execution

  for(i=0; i<RPT; i++) { 
     x = 3.1415926*3.1415926; 
   }

   printf("O"); 
    }
   } 

int main () {
   pthread_t tid1, tid2;pthread_create (&tid1, NULL, &print_X, NULL);
   pthread_create (&tid2, NULL, &print_O, NULL);
  // Wait till threads complete. Not really related to this
  // question in this assignment. Can be ignored.pthread_join(tid1, NULL);pthread_join(tid2, NULL);


 printf ("\n==========================\n");

 }
```

So basically this program is being run 1000 times to slow down execution and the two processes are competing amongst each other to produce the output below.
(The output has line numbers and new lines just to make it more readable.)

01: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
02: OOOOOOOOOOOOOO 
03: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
04: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO 
05: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
06: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO 
07: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
08: XXX 
09: O 
10: X 
11: O 
12: X 
13: O 
14: X 
15: O 
16: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
17: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO 
18: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
19: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO

My only question relates too lines 08 to 15. We are asked what could be the possible reasons for this output (Basically one by one) and I cannot reallyl understand what could happen that each thread would stop and give way to the other 7 times in a row like that? 
The text book goes over concepts like mutual exclusion, deadlocks and starvation but my level of knowledge on this subject can't grasp how this could happen?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The reason is very simple: there are no guarantees, whatsoever, as to the relative scheduling of multiple concurrent execution threads. Not to mention the fact that it's almost a certainty that your compiler has completely ignored all your `for`-loops, since the multiplication can be performed at compile-time, and the compiler can prove that the assignment has no effect, so the whole `for` loop gets flushed down the drain. If this is a sample program that was actually given to you by an instructor, you really, really, need to find a better instructor.

Comment: I understand that there a no guarantees though my question relates to what could have happened though to get an output like this? Hahaha and I will make sure to pass that message on to my instructor

Comment: "No guarantees" means that anything can happen. Your operating system rolled a random number generator and decided to switch to a different scheduling policy. Another program started eating CPU, also forcing a change to the system's scheduling policy. A cosmic ray flipped a few bits inside your computer, resulting in several unexpected context switches. The possibilities are endless.

Comment: This is a bad example because there is lots going on at the same time. First, since you don't have joins, your main program may exit before any of the threads even get to start! So, you could see examples with no output at all. (You may want to check for those!) In addition, the output of buffered; printf does not write to the screen, but rather to a buffer, for performance. The OS then outputs to the screen at its leisure. The threads may have written a lot, but the OS may never have gotten around to write to the screen before the process dies. You need to flush after the printf.